# Can SonarCube apply specified rules to particular codes?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I know that SonarCube could exclude certain codes or modules.

My question is that, currently i have certain project, i only want to scan part of the codes using all SonarCube rules; 
but at same time, for other parts of same project codes, i only want to apply some of the Sonar rules(for example, rules relates to security).

[See this image for my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MHbu.png)

Any experts can give me some hints, whether sonar can do this using maven or not, and how if possible. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a common use case, but I see two options:

1. Create two quality profiles, and analyze your project twice using a different project key and a different quality profile. In SonarQube it will show 2 different projects. Using file inclusion/exclusions, you can partition your modules in the two projects. Note that having two projects could bring some difficulties, for example if you use PR analysis. Still you can have an overall view of the quality using an [application](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Applications) to group them.
2. Keep a single quality profile and single project, but use [advanced issue exclusion](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) patterns to exclude issues you don't want on specific files. Managing those exclusions could be a bit tedious.